# Testing equality of SHA-256 digests using bitwise operators

Tags: php, node.js, sha256

I'm implementing a token system in a nodeJS app where I need to check the equality of two strings that have been hashed using SHA256. My initial idea was that I can simply test equality using a strict equal operator (`hash1 === hash2`) because digests should produce the same string if they had the same input. However, I've seen an article from Paragon Initiative claiming it's safer to compare the strings using bitwise operators on each character's ascii code.

To compare the digest tokens, the Paragon code uses the following code snippet (PHP):

```
public static function hash_equals($hash1, $hash2)
    ...

    $res = 0;
    $len = \strlen($hash1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        $res |= \ord($hash1[$i]) ^ \ord($hash2[$i]);
    }
    return $res === 0;
}
```

Basically, the characters at each index using a bitwise XOR and then saved to a flag value using a bitwise OR. If any of the characters mismatch, then the difference is saved in `$res`.

Is this any more effective than using a strict string comparison? Hash digests are just strings and I don't know why a simple string comparison would be less effective than explicitly checking every sing byte in the strings.

Article Ref: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence
Code Ref: https://github.com/psecio/gatekeeper/blob/7b8ec374e208148692316a34c1b4700d5407ef9b/src/Psecio/Gatekeeper/Gatekeeper.php

### Update:

I looked into it and the `scmp` tool on npm can be used for constant-time string comparisons in Javascript.

As of 4/5/2017, it had no vulnerabilities according to the `nsp` and `snyk` tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: [Use built in hash_equals in PHP for timing attack resistant compares.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83660/simple-string-comparisons-not-secure-against-timing-attacks#answer-83671)
See [hash_equals PHP doc.](http://php.net/manual/de/function.hash-equals.php) Explanation left below.

The reason you shouldn't use string comparisons for testing hashes and such is that they are optimized to return as soon as they can tell the strings aren't equal.

In normal code, this is a good thing.  You want the result as quickly as possible.  When it comes to security though, that leaks information.

If an attacker repeatedly submits different strings and is able to measure a difference in the amount of time until he is denied access, he can use that as a way to determine how much of the substring he has correctly guessed.

Please see [this post on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83660/simple-string-comparisons-not-secure-against-timing-attacks#answer-83670) and [this blog post on timing attacks](https://thisdata.com/blog/timing-attacks-against-string-comparison/) for more information.

Comment: Drawing from what you say, I gather that the point of the for loop in the code I posted is to make sure that the the same amount of time is taken to process the hash digests every single time, processing the entire length of the string even when an error is detected. I guess if I want to use this in my app, I'll just have to implement the same method in javascript.

Comment: Are the bitwise comparisons necessary for this to work? The main point of the solution is that using a regular comparison can result in early returns. If you make sure to compare every single character, does it matter if you use a regular character comparison (`===`) rather than bitwise operators (`^` and `|`) for comparing characters at matching indices?

Comment: @Copernicus it looks like https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-compare may be what you want

Answer (score 0):

Comparing hashes the way you compare normal strings could make your program/app/website/whatever vulnerable to [timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack).
Normal string comparison is fast, you'll get the result as soon as possible. But when it comes to security, that comparison will leak information. By measuring the difference in time it takes to check certain strings an attacker can determine how much of a substring he has guessed correctly. *(Anthony Ferrara has posted a very nice [article](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html) explaining this in detail)*

To prevent that from happening we have to check the two hashes using the exact same time. In PHP (>5.6.0) you can use the timing attack safe string comparison function [`hash_equals()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php).